# Google Sheets: dynamic sum-formula of multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a call tracking sheet for our sales teams to see their numbers.

Now I've following case I don't know how to solve.

Every sales person has his own sheet with his name.
In the main sheet I want to add up the data from all sellers, which currently happens via the following formula:

```
='Closer 1'!C4+'Closer 2'!C4+'Closer 3'!C4+'Closer 4'!C4+'Closer 5'!C4+'Closer 6'!C4+'Closer 7'!C4+'Closer 8'!C4
```

My question now is, how can I dynamically extend the formula with a database table so that when another seller is added, I don't have to adjust a formula?
That the formula is automatically supplemented by the additional person?

Here I added a picture how does it look like: [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGlYT.png)

The Sheet of a sales person looks like: [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNVSU.png)

Because It would need really much time to change all the formulas for every day of the year.

Thank you very much for your help guys!

Comment: you can either use script or go with INDIRECT helper sheet as suggested KD in his answer

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to use INDIRECT function and store sellers names in sum sheet.

[image]

This formula treats string as a reference so you can take sheetnames from your spreadsheet.

My sheet you can find here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f31vxTFhAvmPNzx5oIleZHYfyxnFz73jCHkbP6_5hmA/copy

Comment: Hey!

Thank you very much for your fast reply!

I already using this solution, tut the problem with the solution is that I can't update the variable for over 300 fields. Please check following screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxEA2.png. I have entered the following formula for the selected field
"='Closer 1'!C4+'Closer 2'!C4+'Closer 3'!C4+'Closer 4'!C4+'Closer 5'!C4+'Closer 6'!C4+'Closer 7'!C4+'Closer 8'!C4"

That means if another closer is added, it must be added to the formula and the respective addition per sheet with the row reference.